# Updating fragment every 30 seconds

Tags: android, android-fragments, imageview, updating

I currently have a fragment that generates an ImageView. I am in search of a way to be able to update the imageview that is generated every 30 seconds. The imageview uses other functions to help generate it. 
Thanks for any help.

```
 ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.qrCode);
 try {
        Bitmap bitmap = encodeAsBitmap(STR);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    } catch (WriterException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `Handler` class from the android.os for periodic updates on whatever.

Example code here:

```
final Handler refreshHandler = new Handler();
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // do updates for imageview
                    refreshHandler.postDelayed(this, 30 * 1000);
                }
            };
refreshHandler.postDelayed(runnable, 30 * 1000);
```

Comment: When it try this the imageview is unable to be even initially updated.

Comment: @hahahakebab Yes, because it will be done after 30sec. Put your initial code before the `postDelayed` call.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can use this to run any task every 30 sec.

Something like this:

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.schedule(new TimerTask(){
    @Override
    public void run(){
        Bitmap bitmap = encodeAsBitmap(STR);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }
}, 0, 30000);
```